# Reason behind why Trump may want to lift the Russia sanctions

Tags: donald-trump, sanctions

With **Trump** trying to lift sanctions against **Russia** soon after assuming the presidential role, I'm curious what reasons **Trump** may have for such actions? Would there be good reasons for lifting such sanctions the US people would benefit from or what?

> [President Donald Trump’s administration moved quickly to try and
>   lift economic sanctions on Russia and other punishments former
>   President Barack Obama had put in place as soon as it took office in
>   January, according to multiple sources who have spoken with Yahoo
>   News.](http://www.newsweek.com/trump-white-house-secret-efforts-lift-russia-sanctions-putin-619508)

**Reasoning Note:** *I'm asking as a US citizen and as a voter why the POTUS may reason for a legal decision and with regard to lifting sanctions against foreign governments and assume there's an automatic and always implicit reason why it's fine to ask why the POTUS may have a reason for something since it affects millions of citizens and since he's the commander-in-chief.*

Comment: Non-political expert here, but those who are that may get what I'm saying or asking and if I asked it wrongly, please help me fix with an edit if you want to and get a chance to make this question better if you feel it's worthy enough.

Comment: Please help to improve this question if you are voting to close based on: 'The primary purpose of this question appears to be to promote or discredit a specific political cause, group or politician. It does not appear to be a good-faith effort to learn more about governments, policies and political processes as defined in the help center.' I think this question doesn't fill the requirements listed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reasons for sanctions:**
The sanctions were originally placed as a message for Russia that US doesn't approve Russia's involvement in Ukraine war/crisis and taking of the Crimean peninsula. Other countries including the EU have also put in place such sanctions. Removing these sanctions before Russia has rectified the situation is a message that US no longer has an issue about Russia's aggressive geopolitical actions. This might lead to Russia pursuing other similar quests.

In addition to the Ukraine/Crimea sanctions there are sanctions put in place for interference of Russia in US presidential elections. The same logic applies as above.

**Reasons against sanctions:**
The Ukraine/Crimea sanctions have lead to financial losses for all of the parties involved, and so removing them would benefit the US too. Also this would better the relations between the US and Russia which might be preferable for solving other issues together rather than separately e.g. the war on ISIS.

Trump may now want to remove only the sanctions due to Russia's election interference to further discredit claims of the election interference. Trumps teams ties to Russia during the elections is obviously currently an issue he would like to see gone.

Comment: Huh? The sanctions being discussed weren't placed on Russia for their actions in Ukraine/Crimea.

Comment: Please enlighten me. https://www.state.gov/e/eb/tfs/spi/ukrainerussia/

Comment: Also from the OP's linked article: 'The sanctions in question included those imposed by Obama for Russia’s annexation of Crimea in 2014 and others inflicted late last year to punish Moscow for its suspected efforts to interfere in the 2016 election.'

Comment: @Communisty Take a look over https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/26510/where-could-the-f-b-i-investigation-go-after-a-finding-that-trump-interfered in case you can provide some detail there too if you get a chance.

Answer (score -1):

> Donald Trump has pursued business deals in Russia since 1987, and has sometimes traveled there to explore potential business opportunities. In 1996, Trump trademark applications were submitted for potential Russian real estate development deals. Trump's partners and children have repeatedly visited Moscow, connecting with developers and government officials to explore joint venture opportunities.
>   [Wikipedia: Business projects of Donald Trump in Russia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_projects_of_Donald_Trump_in_Russia)

Comment: Have no idea what this have to do with sanctions as there are more profitable business deals elsewhere.  Seems like a lot of trouble to go through for a tiny drop in the bucket. In the end, this opinion shows little understanding of business and wealth creation.